# Get X and Y coordinates onClick

Tags: android

I used to have an `onTouchListener`, but I needed to change it to an `onClickListener` because I didn't want long touches to record different values than short touches. In one of my lines of code, I had `X[i]=Integer.valueOf((int)event.getX());`, which worked perfectly with an `onTouchListener`, but with an `onClickListener`, I get the error `event cannot be resolved`.

**My question is, is there a `event.getX()` function for an `onClickListener`?**

Here is the portion of my code:

```
    touchLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            X[i]=Integer.valueOf((int)event.getX());
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may should look this, that may help you:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 Log.i("222","X-"+x+"===Y="+y);

        }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

I am pretty sure you cannot get the click x and y coords because OnClick is an event which is triggered by the view's internal implementation of the touch listener. It is triggered when the user lifts his finger and it has not moved more than a certain distance(called touch slop).

On the other hand if you implement your own touch listener, you can detect where the touch gesture started and ended and do whatever you need with these coordinates. It would look something like this:

```
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                startX = (int) event.getX();
                startY = (int) event.getY();
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                int endX = (int) event.getX();
                int endY = (int) event.getY();
                int dX = Math.abs(endX - startX);
                int dY = Math.abs(endY - startY);


                if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dX, 2) + Math.pow(dY, 2)) <= touchSlop) {
                    // Your on click logic here...
                    return true;
                }
            }
       return false;
    }
});
```

The touchSlop variable here holds how much you can move before the gesture is considered scrolling. You can get this value by calling ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop().

Comment: return true; shuld be below // Your on click logic here... 
But on the end of method you should return false.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
      public void onClick(View view) {
        int[] values = new int[2]; 
        view.getLocationOnScreen(values);
        Log.d("X & Y",values[0]+" "+values[1]);
    }
```

In Method

```
      getLocationOnScreen(values);
```

you can do whatever you want.If it not work in your case , please let me know

Comment: This is because the values returned by the "getLocationOnScreen" method in the View are of the views most top left point, not the point that the view was actually touched at.